Is there a file uploader like Dreamweaver's?
I have been using Dreamweaver for years to upload files. I used to use it to create websites, looong ago. I now use VSCode and Notepad++.
However, I still need to keep Dreamweaver around just to sync my files to the server. And no, FileZilla (at least the free version) doesn't do most of the functions I need ASFAICT. I really don't want to buy an Adobe subscription just for this - my version of Dreamweaver is very old (Version CS5.5)... from the days when you bought software.
Here are the features I need:

Get or Put newer files just by clicking on the directory (or entire site) and then clicking sync.

Get and Put new files using the above sequence.
Cloak a directory so it doesn't get synced even if it is selected
(mainly for subdirectories)

Option to delete files that don't exist in the source of both Get
and Put

Option to switch from and to local and server list of files (FileZilla shows this)

Open the file in the editor, edit, then Put it

Alert when an external editor changes a file in the editor file so I can Put it


The last two are not as important, but I find them very useful when trying quick experiments.
Is there any other software that has all or most of the above? Ideally FOSS, but willing to pay for something good. Git is not an option for various reasons.
This is for Windows 10 and I upload to a Debian Server. I mostly work with PHP & JavaScript, if that matters.

I use Notepad++'s NPP FTP plugin to edit the files on the website directly, and an FTP client such as FileZilla to make backups before I start so I can always go back to an earlier version that way.

Check Winscp. This might cater to all the requirements that you have.

Downloaded.  Will try it soon,

Hi Kumar,  link only answers tend to get deleted as the link can disappear.  And you are supposed to give a recommendation, which implies some more information.

Doesn't seem to do everything, but I think I just need to learn it.  I am awarding the bonus to you anyway.
